# Laravel - Carbon giving wrong time when using shiftTimeZone and setTimeZone

Tags: laravel, datetime, laravel-8, php-carbon

Laravel carbon is returning time in UTC when printing `Carbon::now()` but doesn't give the correct time while using `shiftTimezone` and `setTimezone`

Below are the results:

```
Carbon::now(); //"2021-07-20T07:30:29.775871Z"
Carbon::now()->timezoneName; //UTC
Carbon::now()->shiftTimezone('Asia/Kolkata'); //"2021-07-20T02:00:29.452997Z"
Carbon::now()->shiftTimezone('+05:30'); //"2021-07-20T02:00:29.452997Z"
Carbon::now()->shiftTimezone('Asia/Kolkata'); //"2021-07-20T07:30:29.775871Z"
```

In case of shiftTimeZone, it should add 05:30 hours to the time. But what it actually does is reduces 05:30 from the UTC time.
And for setTimezone it is taking the same time as UTC.

Any idea where I'm getting it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce the issue with Carbon. Here is my test:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
Carbon::now(); // "2023-09-15 01:16:27.000000 UTC (+00:00)"
Carbon::now()->timezoneName; // UTC
Carbon::now()->shiftTimezone('Asia/Kolkata'); // "2023-09-15 01:16:27.000000 Asia/Kolkata (+05:30)"
Carbon::now()->shiftTimezone('+05:30'); // "2023-09-15 01:16:27.000000 +05:30"
Carbon::now()->shiftTimezone('Asia/Kolkata'); // "2023-09-15 01:16:27.000000 Asia/Kolkata (+05:30)"
Carbon::now()->setTimezone('Asia/Kolkata'); // "2023-09-15 06:46:27.000000 Asia/Kolkata (+05:30)"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my application, I never use `shiftTimezone` or `setTimezone`.

I always go with something like the following:

```
Carbon::now()->timezone('Asia/Kolkata');
```

It returns me the date in `Asia/Kolkata` timezone, without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you put in comments here is not the content of the instance, it's an UTC ISO-8601 string as it's converted to be rendered in JSON output for instance:

```php
echo Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u p'); // 2021-07-20 09:36:08.596951 Z
echo Carbon::now()->shiftTimezone('Asia/Kolkata')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u p'); // 2021-07-20 09:36:08.596951 +05:30
echo Carbon::now()->shiftTimezone('+05:30')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u p'); // 2021-07-20 09:36:08.596951 +05:30
echo Carbon::now()->shiftTimezone('Asia/Kolkata')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u p'); // 2021-07-20 09:36:08.596951 +05:30
```

JSON is converted to UTC because it's a standard way to exchange datetime information, timezone should be a separated information and you only need it to  force a timezone, but 99% you want the user/client/browser to use its own timezone so `new Date('2021-07-20T09:36:08.596951Z')` in JavaScript or equivalent in other languages will work just fine and apply the current device timezone, which is the correct way for proper localization. Very specific cases where you want to display a date in a timezone that IS NOT the user device timezone, then you should pass `"Asia/Kolkata"` explicitly in your JSON output.